# How to remove the public IP auto settings from an Auto Scaling Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

I've set up an Auto scaling group that triggers new EC2 instances and this works fine, but in my initial iteration, I somehow activated the fact that EC2 instances need a public IP, but I don't want that.

Unfortunately, I can't find where in my configuration I can toggle this to disable associating a public IP on my instances. I'm not even sure it's on the Autoscaling configuration or somewhere else.

How can I disable the public IP association for newly created EC2 instances via Auto scaling group?

Comment: Are you launching the Auto Scaling group in a Public Subnet? Instances would normally go into a Private Subnet.

Comment: Thank you for this, you made me go to the right path: I'm using a Launch Configuration, and when editing the configuration, if you go on "Advanced", you can define the behavior for the IP, which I set to private only.

Comment: Please try to refrain from adding conversational/chatty material to your posts, as per prior edits. Thank you Cyril.

Comment: @halfer This is debatable. I prefer to remain polite.

Comment: The discussion has been done on Meta _ad nauseum_, and the settled view of the community is that technical writing is preferred. It's not 100% unanimous, but it is the majority. It is also in the Help Centre.

Answer (score 3):

See [Modify the public IPv4 addressing attribute for your subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#subnet-public-ip):

1. Open the Amazon VPC console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Subnets.
3. Select your subnet and choose Subnet Actions, Modify auto-assign IP
   settings.
4. The Enable auto-assign public IPv4 address check box, if selected,
   requests a public IPv4 address for all instances launched into the
   selected subnet. Select or clear the check box as required, and then
   choose Save.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod for your help. Is there a way to configure that at the Autoscaling level ? I kind of remember that I had the choice to set "use default" or enable/disable, but I don't know where it is.

Comment: Or maybe Autoscaling only use the default configuration from the VPC as you suggested and I'm thinking of something else ?

Comment: AutoScaling Launch Configuration options include whether or not to auto-assign a public IPv4 address (via AssociatePublicIpAddress).